# Объединение массивов PHP

Tags: php

Имеется два массива:

```
$products =   [ 1, 4, 3, 5, 2 ];
$quantities = [ 4, 2, 7, 2, 2 ];
```

Как их объединить так, чтобы результат объединения имел следующий вид:

```
[
    '1' => '4',
    '4' => '2',
    '3' => '7',
    '5' => '2',
    '2' => '2'
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array_combine($products, $quantities)
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$newArray = array_intersect_key($quantities, array_flip($products));
```